# Can anyone please explain me the following function from eloquent javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function countBy(items, groupName) {
   let counts = [];
   for (let item of items) {
      let name = groupName(item);
      let known = counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name);
      if (known == -1) {
         counts.push({
            name,
            count: 1
         });
      } else {
         counts[known].count++;
      }
   }
   return counts;
}

console.log(countBy([1, 2, 3], n => n > 2));
// → [{name: false, count: 2}, {name: true, count: 1}]
```

At the third iteration when item is 3 I would have thought that the value of name is true (which is correct) and known is 0. (because counts = [name = false, count: 2] hence findindex of "name" is 0) but in reality known = -1 .

Can you please explain me why known= -1 (which means that the element is not found, but according to my thinking "name" is found at [name = false, count: 2].)

Many thanks for your thoughts and consideration in advance!!!

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: Check that again. You just said that in the third iteration, the value of `name` is `true` (which is correct). Then later you claim that `known` should be 0, but the reality is that `counts = [{name: false, count: 2}]` at that point, which does not contain an element with `name: true`, which is the value of `name` searched in `counts.findIndex()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Actually on your third iteration `counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name);` is returning `-1`
Because `findIndex` couldn't find any value that satisfies your function `c => c.name == name`

**First iteration**
`

```
item = 1;
name = groupName(item); // name = false, since item => item > 2
known = counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name); // known = -1
counts = [{name: false, count: 1}]
```

`

**Second iteration**
`

```
item = 2;
name = groupName(item); // name = false, since item => item > 2
known = counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name); // known = 0
counts = [{name: false, count: 2}]
```

`

**Third iteration**
`

```
item = 3;
name = groupName(item); // name = true, since item => item > 2
known = counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name); // known = -1
counts = [
           {name: false, count: 2},
           {name: true, count: 1}
         ];
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the function is correct because in the third iteration name is True and there is not other element with the value of True in the property name.

counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name);
What this function those is simple, compare {"name": False, count:0}.name == True. so the result is -1

Answer (score 0):

At third iteration,

when item is 3,

groupName(3) is true,

counts is [{name: false, count:2}],

now findIndex of all name property of element of counts does not match groupName(3), so returns index of -1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

I repeat, the comparison of findIndex is c.name versus name, whereas c.name is the property of element of counts, at that time only one --- false.

Let me take another example for you :

`console.log(countBy(["apple", "chair", "banana", "table"], item => item == "apple" || "banana"? "fruits" : "furniture"));
// → [{name: "fruits", count: 2}, {name: "furniture", count: 2}]`

At fourth iteration,
counts = [{name: "fruits", count: 2}, {name: "furniture", count: 1}] 
name = groupName("table") = "furniture"
So the findIndex returns 1.

But at second teration,
counts = [{name: "fruits", count: 1}] 
name = groupName("chair") = "furniture"
No match, so the findIndex returns - 1.
and the function creates {name: "furniture", count :1} and append to counts.

Ok, maybe this is where you don't understand. At creation, you see

{name, counts: 1}

It is a shorthand, 
it actually is
    `{
        name : name,
        count : 1
    }`

where name (key, "name") : name (value, result of groupName(item).

Answer (score -1):

`countBy` takes an array of elements and groups them, and gets the count of each group.

How it groups them is defined by the `groupName` function, which takes an element from the array and decides what the group name is. in this case `n => n > 2` is the group function, which means you have 2 group names: 'true' and 'false', 'true' for everything > 2, and 'false' for everything else.

So you have 2 groups: true and false, as defined by your groupName function, and the output is the count of all the items in your array in each group. There are 2 items less than or equal to 2, hence `{name: false, count: 2}`, and one item that is greater than 2, hence `{name: true, count: 1}`

You could try altering the name function, for example instead of `n => n > 2` you could have `n => n % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'` and see the output then.