# Implicit binding assignment for an object's elements? (JavaScript arrow functions, Ch05 Eloquent JS)

Tags: javascript, object, arrow-functions

Specifically, I'm curious about the binding that was created for "c" in the "known" variable definition within the for...of statement.

```
function countBy(items, groupName) {
  let counts = [];
  for (let item of items) {
    let name = groupName(item);
    let known = counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name);
    if (known == -1) {
      counts.push({name, count: 1});
    } else {
      counts[known].count++;
    }
  }
  return counts;
}

console.log(countBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n => n > 2));
// → [{name: false, count: 2}, {name: true, count: 3}]
```

I understand that "c" here represents an element of the "counts" array of objects. However, I do not understand why "c" can be correctly interpreted as representing an element of "counts".

Is its assignment to each of counts' elements implicit, given there are no other object elements that it could be representing? Or does the arrow function

```
c => c.name == name
```

implicitly (i) define and (ii) then utilize c as a binding for objects' elements?

This code comes from Chapter 5 of Eloquent JavaScript. I tried searching the previous thread about it ([Can anyone please explain me the following function from eloquent javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378374/can-anyone-please-explain-me-the-following-function-from-eloquent-javascript)) but was unable to reach a conclusion.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `function (c) { return c.name == name; }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: Yes, `c` is defined as the parameter of the arrow function. Longer: `(c) => { return c.name == name; }`

Comment: Thank you, both. For future readers: I also realized that "c" will always be interpreted as belonging to the "counts" array, given that the .findIndex method is being implemented on "counts". So, obviously "c" (or whatever binding you use to refer to the elements of "objects") refers to the elements of "counts".

Comment: Yet another point to understand is that, its possible because *arrow functions* tend to automatically bind the `this` context to the function with the right element from the array.